# Error when building Apache 2.4.25 from source with open ssl 1.1.0c

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, httpd, openssl

I have built Apache 2.4.25 with OpenSSL 1.0.2 successfully.

But Because of some security holes we found in our Internal tests,
I have been asked to patch Openssl with the latest version.
So I am **trying to build Apache httpd 2.4.25 with OpenSSL 1.1.0c (or) 1.1.0d**

My Environments

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.11
Codename:       Tikanga

Perl:           5.24
PCRE:           8.38
APR:            1.5.2
APR-util:       1.5.4
OpenSSL:        1.1.0c / 1.1.0d
```

All the above Apache dependencies have been successfully built and installed

Apache 2.4.25 - Installation steps

```
cd /my/softwares
tar -xvf httpd-2.4.25.tar -C /my/build/

cd /my/build/httpd-2.4.25/

./configure --prefix=/my/apache-httpd-2.4.25 \
    --with-pcre=/my/dependencies/pcre-8.38/ \
    --with-apr=/my/dependencies/apr-1.5.2 \
    --with-apr-util=/my/dependencies/apr-util-1.5.4 \
    --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c \
    --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
    --enable-mods-static=ssl

make // see below errors
make install
```

I am getting the below error when building Apache from source with open ssl.
Please help me in the right directions.

```
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'make_dh_params':
ssl_engine_init.c:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c:63: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c:63: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_ctx_protocol':
ssl_engine_init.c:519: warning: 'TLSv1_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1598)
ssl_engine_init.c:520: warning: 'TLSv1_server_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1597)
ssl_engine_init.c:525: warning: 'TLSv1_1_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1604)
ssl_engine_init.c:526: warning: 'TLSv1_1_server_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1603)
ssl_engine_init.c:530: warning: 'TLSv1_2_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1610)
ssl_engine_init.c:531: warning: 'TLSv1_2_server_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1609)
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_ctx_session_cache':
ssl_engine_init.c:641: warning: passing argument 2 of 'SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb' from incompatible pointer type
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'use_certificate_chain':
ssl_engine_init.c:861: warning: implicit declaration of function 'BIO_s_file_internal'
ssl_engine_init.c:861: warning: passing argument 1 of 'BIO_new' makes pointer from integer without a cast
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_server_certs':
ssl_engine_init.c:1201: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make[3]: *** [ssl_engine_init.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/my/build/httpd-2.4.25/modules/ssl'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/my/build/httpd-2.4.25/modules/ssl'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/my/build/httpd-2.4.25/modules'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-announce/2017-February/000095.html

Comment: Stop. RHEL 5 goes out of production phase (and therefore out of support) at the end of this quarter. You need to upgrade to the current release immediately.

Comment: @istheEnglishway Are you trying to say that it's worth building Apache with the latest openssl release ?  I will try them tomorrow and keep you updated.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Yes, we are aware of them, but because of budget constraint we can't afford to upgrade.

Comment: What do you mean budget constraint? You already have the subscription, don't you? Or are you running this machine without a subscription?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not sure about subscriptions. When asked to the server team - they replied that our project hasn't got any more funding to upgrade.

Comment: Did they mean for you to shut down at the end of 1Q2017 then? Or do they just not want to actually do any work to upgrade the server? Obviously you don't have to pay anything extra for a subscription if you already have one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53698/discussion-between-user292049-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of now**, with the latest version Apache HTTPD 2.4.25, the 2.4 branch is **not yet compatible with Openssl 1.1.x**, you will have to stick with the latest 1.0.2x if you want to stay up to date on security issues.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please let me know where to find more info about them - I tried googling but couldn't find any concrete details.

Comment: There is no official statement, since OpenSSL 1.1.x became stable pratically "yesterday" there haven't been time and time to adapt 2.4 branch to it, all of this you can read about mainly in the dev and user httpd mailing list.